# TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'payload'

Tags: discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class GetRole(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name = '역할')
    async def GetRoles(self, ctx):
        m = await ctx.send(':one: 을 눌러 <@&817598594009661450> 역할을 얻으세요.\n:two: 를 눌러 <@&817978024700018719> 역할을 얻으세요.\n:three: 를 눌러 <@&817978098531172362> 역할을 얻으세요.')
        await m.add_reaction('1️⃣')


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, ctx, payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
        user = self.bot.get_user(payload.id)
        if user.bot:
            return

        if str(payload.reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
            role = self.bot.get_role(817598594009661450)
            await user.add_roles(role)
            await user.send('DONE!')
    
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(GetRole(bot))
```

yeah. i tried it, but error has occured

TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'payload'

How I fix this error?

Comment: As the error log says, you are calling the function `on_raw_reaction_add()` and not passing  value for `payload`. Is this the whole code?

Comment: yes. how passing the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) event does not receive both a Context and a RawReactionActionEvent object; only the payload is given, so your listener should only have two arguments in it which is `self`, and `payload`.